# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.Gson.newBuilder()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to use Unirest in my program but I keep getting this error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.Gson.newBuilder()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;`

I have tried using different maven versions of Gson but I still continue to get this seror

Edid added my pom.xml, I tried deleted my .m2 but I am still having this problem

````
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.konghq/unirest-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.konghq</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.00</version>
            <classifier>standalone</classifier>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>[4.0,)</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>Spigot8</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.8</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>```
````

Comment: It looks like the method is only in [Gson 2](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/Gson.html), not Gson 1. Unirest uses [Gson 2.8.5](https://github.com/Kong/unirest-java/blob/master/object-mapper-gson/pom.xml#L30) Can you show your Maven dependencies?

Comment: @Yserbius Added

Answer (score 2):

Could be a conflict between the GSON versions in your POM file versus what is in your container (Tomcat/JBoss) etc. Inspect the JARS in WEB-INF/lib. If there are two different versions, then delete the one which is not the same as the one currently in your maven project's POM file. I had a similar issue - my project was using gson-2.6.3.jar but a conflicting gson-2.1.jar also existed in WEB-INF/lib. I deleted  gson-2.1.jar and this resolved my problem

Answer (score 0):

This issue is possibly due to conflicts in Gson versions.

Go to your repository if you are on windows:

> C:\Users\User_name.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson

or on Mac:-

> /.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson

Delete all the existing folders.

Now, add below maven dependency in your pom file:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Re-build your maven project and try to run.

Comment: I have tried this twice and it still does not seem to work.

Comment: @user13192903 try to use version 2.8.6 version of gson, but the existing repository in m2 and try clean build.

Comment: I tried doing both but it stlll does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a dependencies issue.

Please make sure your dependencies are correct. Unirest 3.7.00 uses Gson 2.8.6

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.konghq/unirest-java/3.7.00

Also, if you don't use Gson separately you don't need to specify it. Just add a dependency for unirest-java as it's described in Maven repository:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.konghq</groupId>
    <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.00</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hey I have tried this along with many other things, but I still cannot get it. i also now get `> [18:39:44 WARN]: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class kong.unirest.json.JSONObject
`

Comment: I know, such things happen sometimes :-) I can't see your code so I still believe there's a conflict in versions (sometimes it's just duplicates in dependencies) or incorrect usage. I'd start the separate project strongly following the docs http://kong.github.io/unirest-java/ and see if it works.